# Returning result of std::bind

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I've managed to figure out how to use `std::bind` to replace a whole bunch of code that previously triggered C-style callbacks (not shown here) via a web of static variables, static functions, and a compiler extension `__closure`.

This code compiles and runs successfully; however, in trying to make a slight improvement I get a weird compiler error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

typedef void MyFunc(std::string &);

struct Master
{
    void func(std::string &s) { std::cout << "Master::func(" << s << ")\n"; }
    void go();
    Master() {}

private:
    Master(Master const &);
};

int main()
{
    Master m;
    m.go();
}

void call_function( std::function<MyFunc> fp, std::string s )
{
    fp(s);
}

template<typename FuncT, typename Host>
typename std::function<FuncT> my_binder(Host *h, FuncT Host::*p)
{
    using std::placeholders::_1;
    return std::bind(p, h, _1);
}

void Master::go()
{
    std::string s("hello");

    // OK
    using std::placeholders::_1;
    std::function<MyFunc> f = std::bind(&Master::func, this, _1);
    call_function(f, s);
    call_function( std::bind(&Master::func, this, _1), s );

    // Undefined structure 'boost::function<void(std::string &)>'
    my_binder(this, &Master::func);

    // I'm hoping to end up here
    // call_function( my_binder(this, &Master::func), s );
}
```

The code appears to work in latest g++ and clang, but gives

> ```
>    // Undefined structure 'boost::function<void(std::string &)>'
> ```

on another compiler which has not-quite-c++11 support. Is my code correct (i.e. the failing compiler has a bug)?

Also: is there a pre-existing template I can use instead of `my_binder`? My aim is to make it so that people can call `call_function` as easily as possible, without having to muck around with including `std::placeholders` and so on.  Of course this is possible with a preprocessor macro but it'd be nice to use a template function.

Comment: Maybe the compiler can't infer the template arguments and they need to be added manually to your my_binder call.

Comment: How's `boost::function` getting pulled by the compiler to define `my_binder`?

Comment: It does `using boost::function` in namespace std

Comment: Have you tried `boost::function<void,std::string &>` instead of `boost::function<void(std::string &)>`

Comment: @MikeMB `Too many arguments passed to template 'boost::function<Signature>'`

Comment: Which version of boost and which compiler are you using?

Comment: Sorry, i meant `boost::function2<void,std::string &>`

Comment: `Too few arguments passed to template 'boost::function2<R,T0,T1>'`. Using bcc32 6.70 with bundled Boost 1.50.0

Comment: My main question is whether or not my code is actually correct as-is (so that I know whether or not to file a bug report).